# Python set attribute equal to another attribute

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a class attribute targeting another attribute from the same object and have a function to update the value of the target?

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_1 = 1
        self.var_2 = 2
        self.var_3 = 3
        self.current_var = self.var_1

    def update_var(self, value):
        self.current_var = ...
```

Expected outcome:

```
>>> x = MyObject()
>>> x.update_var(10)
>>> x.var_1
10
>>> x.current_var = x.var_2
>>> x.update_var(5)
>>> x.var_2
5
```

Comment: pass the object to the constructor

Comment: Can you give a more meaningful example, your code will raise an error because you are calling MyObject.update_var without an instance

Comment: If you update `var_1` or `current_var`, one update will not change the other, no

Comment: You can do this manually: `self.current_var = self.var_1 = value`

Comment: Just made an edit to clarify there is only one object. I want to update `var_1` by using `current_var`. Not sure how to explain other than `current_var` doesn't equal a value it equals the `var_1` attribute

Comment: You should also outline your reasoning why this appears to be necessary in your case. Maybe you are trying to solve the wrong thing. (Also see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/18771) - you are asking for a way to do something that you think is the solution to an otherwise unexplained problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest making `current_var` a property that acts as a proxy for a given instance attribute. You can use `set_current_var` to update the proxy target.

### Code

```
class MyObject(object):
    current_var = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_1 = 1
        self.var_2 = 2
        self.var_3 = 3

    def set_current_var(self, name):
        self._current_var = name

    @property
    def current_var(self):
        return getattr(self, self._current_var)

    @current_var.setter
    def current_var(self, value):
        setattr(self, self._current_var, value)
```

### Example

```
x = MyObject()

print(x.var_1) # 1

x.set_current_var('var_1')

print(x.current_var) # 1

x.current_var = 4

print(x.var_1) # 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the __dict__ of the object or as said by @bla [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr),
And Enum so you don't use string to specify the attribute:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_1 = 1
        self.var_2 = 2
        self.var_3 = 3
        self.current_var = None
    def update_var(self, value):
        if self.current_var is None:
            raise Exception('Current var is not set')
        self.__dict__[self.current_var.name] = value
        setattr(self, self.current_var.name, value) # Same result

m = MyObject()

attrs = vars(m)
attrs_enum = Enum("attrs_enum", attrs)


m.var_1 # 1
m.current_var = attrs_enum.var_1
m.update_var(10)
m.var_1 # 10

m.current_var = attrs_enum.var_2
m.var_2 # 2
m.update_var(20)
m.var_2 # 20
```

I don't like using a string to specify the attribute, but this is solution

Comment: You could also use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: How could you specify the attribute other than a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class for your `MyObject` attribute values. That way, a reference will exist from the contents of `current_var` to the attribute bound in `__dict__`:

```
class _int:
   def __init__(self, _val):
     self.value = _val
   def __repr__(self):
     return str(self.value)

class MyObject(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.var_1 = _int(1)
    self.var_2 = _int(2)
    self.var_3 = _int(3)
    self.current_var = self.var_1
  def update_var(self, value):
    self.current_var.value = value

x = MyObject()
x.update_var(10)
print(x.var_1)
x.current_var = x.var_2
x.update_var(5)
print(x.var_2)
```

Output:

```
10
5
```